# Reading in data from txt file and Adding it to an Observable Collection

Tags: c#, file-io, load, save, observablecollection

I'm attempting to build a simple save-and-load program that reads Users in from a text file, adds it to an observable collection, and then populates a listbox with the observable collection of Users.

While I understand how to add Users to my observable collection and then write that collection to the the txt file, I am confused as to how I am supposed to read-in a user and re-add him to the the ObservableCollection of users.

my user class:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Problem method:

```
 ObservableCollection<User> LoadActionList = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("SavedAccounts.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while (!file.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = file.ReadLine();
                //LoadActionList.Add(line); //how to detect that a line is a User?
            }
            file.Close();
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing text files for this you should look into serialization.

Check this out: http://tanguay.info/web2010/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=224

Comment: That was very helpful. Way simpler than what I was doing too. Thanks!